# Create a new column name in SQL based on results

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012, pivot

So I have a SQL query that outputs say 15 columns of data. I have 3 rows.

All rows results are identical apart from 2 fields. I want to group all the results onto 1 line and create new columns and enter the value of the fields

Example

[image: Account-Name-Value-UserCreatedBy-Date 1234 This 1 Me 01/01/2001 1234 Is 2 Me 01/01/2001 1234 Test 3 Me 01/01/2001]

But I want the results to look like this

[image]

Thanks in advance you beautiful people

SQL VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)

```
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: What's your DBMS? Knowing the DBMS, probably we'll be able to pivot the data dynamically.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64) 
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
Does this help?

Comment: Just `SQL Server 2012` is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SELECT` Statement containing `XML PATH` Clause in order to get dynamic pivot. Let's create a temporary table(`#tab`) first in order to number the columns(`Name` and `Value`) with changing values through use of `ROW_NUMBER()` function(Indeed,you can directly use `Value` column instead of generating sequential numbers, but I intentionally leave that function to get a generic solution ).

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Account] ORDER BY [Value]) AS rn
   FROM [tab]
)
SELECT *, CONCAT('Value',rn) AS rn_v, CONCAT('Name',rn) AS rn_n 
 INTO #tab
 FROM t
```

and then use it within the following code to get the desired result set

```
DECLARE @colsv1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @colsv2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   
        @colsn1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @colsn2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @colsv1 = 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Value',[rn])) 
         FROM #tab FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
     
SELECT @colsv2 = 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 'MAX('+QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Value',[rn]))+') AS '
                           + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Value',[rn]))
         FROM #tab FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
     
SELECT @colsn1 = 
STUFF(
      (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Name',[rn])) 
         FROM #tab FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');

SELECT @colsn2 = 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 'MAX('+QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Name',[rn]))+') AS '
                           + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Name',[rn]))
         FROM #tab FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
     
SET  @query = 
 N'SELECT [Account],'+ @colsv2 +','+ @colsn2 + ',[UserCreatedBy],[Date]'+
 N'  FROM #tab
    PIVOT 
    (
      MAX([Value]) FOR [rn_v] IN ('+ @colsv1 + N')
    ) AS p1
    PIVOT
    (
      MAX([Name])  FOR [rn_n] IN ('+ @colsn1 + N')
    ) AS p2 
    GROUP BY [Account],[UserCreatedBy],[Date] ';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=fe732436338f7c142c5b2e884ff545f0)</kbd>